# Find out what application prevents renaming a directory

Tags: windows, filesystems

Sometimes the update process of our application fails to rename a directory on the user's machine. Is it possible to easily find out **with a standard Windows command line tool** (no GUI application) which process has "open" a certain directory or file below the very directory, so we can tell the user to close that process?

Comment: Are the computers joined into a domain, and do you have domain administrative privileges?

Comment: I usually use Process explorer, search for the filename, and if I'm lucky, it will be an open handle by a process I have sufficient access to control. if its PID=4 though, you won't be able to do anything without a reboot.

Comment: @LPChip I don't know, but I reckon no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from Microsoft isn't included with Windows by default but is from Microsoft and can do this. Download and install the tool from that link, run it, go to Find -> Find Handle or DLL, and enter the path to the file or directory, and it will return a list of processes with a handle to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unlocker program,  the easiest and fastest way,  google it its free

Comment: And it usually requires a reboot, which for the scope of this question is pointless because a reboot itself already fixes the issue.